# fortran compiler optimization of do cycle in include statement

Tags: fortran

I have a large Fortran code for HPC where several equations are solved over a computational grid. So in many places in the source code are placed nested do cycle to loop over the entair computational domain, shuch as

```
do k = 1,number_of_point_in_z
  do j = 1,number_of_point_in_y
    do i = 1,number_of_point_in_x
      ... some operations ...
    end do
  end do
end do
```

I would like to replace these lines with a single statment and I found the only solution to be the use of include statment, as

```
include 'start_domain_cycle'
      ... some operations ...
include 'end_domain_cycle'
```

with two files named start_domain_cycle and end_domain_cycle defined as follow

```
block
  integer :: i, j, k
  do k = 1,number_of_point_in_z
    do j = 1,number_of_point_in_y
      do i = 1,number_of_point_in_x
```

and

```
      end do
    end do
  end do
end block
```

My questions are:

1. will the compiler be able to optimize this code when compiling with optimizations? (for example -O3 with gfortran)
2. are there better solutions to avoid hard coding every time the do loop?

Comment: `include` is not a statement, as a trivial comment. More importantly, your use of "cycle" _is_ potentially confusing. Do you mean to imply that there is a `cycle` in the DO construct, or do you mean "loop"?

Comment: As personal style, I'd recommend avoiding this use of include lines: although it's potentially tedious to write out those loops explicitly, it's entirely clear what's going on to anyone reading. That is personal preference, but to help anyone who shares your preference or mine, can you add some detail about what happens in those loops? You may get suggestions about using a function, another type of loop construct, or something else entirely different.  Not knowing about the style of loop makes most of those suggestions guesses.

Comment: @francescalus inside the loop there can be computations such as the evaluation of a gradient of a scalar function or the time advancing of an equation; in addition there can be output operations. I hope examples are wide enough to clear out the possible operations in the loops.

Comment: A lot of these kinds of loops can be made implicit, by using `elemental` constructs. Hard to say if this applies to your cases without more details.

Comment: @veryreverie according to my expirience, it is more efficient to call a subroutine and perform inside the subroutine the triple do loop instad of calling a function for every i,j,k. Am I wrong?

Comment: It really depends what you are doing inside the loop. And as ever with optimisation, the way to find the most efficient approach is to profile your code and try out different options. But yes,  a lot of the time, `do... a(i,j,k) = f(b(i,j,k)) enddo...` is more efficient when written `a = f(b)` with an `elemental` function `f`. And it's certainly easier to read.

Comment: @veryreverie I apologize for the unclearness of my previous comment. I was not comparing `a = f(b)` with `do... a(i,j,k) = f(b(i,j,k)) enddo...` but with `do... a(i,j,k) = direct body of function f enddo...`. Additionally, the elemental function cannot be used if the function f does not operates only on (i,j,k) but also on closer nodes (like when computing derivatives) right?

Comment: With return value optimisation and the potential for inlining, there's no reason to believe `a = f(b)` would be any slower than either of the other options. And it's infinitely easier to read. If the (likely tiny) performance differences involved are important to your application, you absolutely need to profile both methods to find out which is faster.

Comment: For functions which also operate on closer nodes, there are no general solutions, and we'd need to see what you're actually doing inside the loop in order to be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

1. The source code present in the include files is first inserted where the `include` are, then the complete code is compiled. So from an optimisation point of view it makes no difference.
2. A matter of personal preference... I find it more readable to have the whole code together, but this is just my opinion. You could also append the 3 `do` on a single line (with shorter variable names for readability)

```
do k = 1,nz ; do j = 1,ny ; do i = 1,nx
```

Comment: I'm sure your point 1 is correct. But why do you recommend writing all 3 `do` statements on one line?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Just to shorten (in number of lines) the part of the code that only consists in (repeated) control structures, if it really matters... It's still a single line, but clearer than the `include` solution